# PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp event doesn't get called when mouse clicked

Tags: c#, events, button, mouseevent

I have a listview in which I display objects with their state and name. The state is surrounded by a button and when I click on it the state changes from active to inactive or the other way round.
Now I want to change the state when I click the mouse button down and change it back when the mouse button goes up. My button has to event "PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" and "PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" as you can see in the code below. In the SendStateMessage() method the state is send to a SCADA-Server and the server sends me the new state back and the GUI edits the change.

Normally it doesn't make any problems, but when I click to fast the "PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" event doesn't get called. So the "MouseUp" is not shown at the consol.

I tried to call a Task.Delay() in the first mouseDown event because i thougt that the method needs some more time but this didn't work well. So i want to ask you if somebody has an idea what the problem could be and a way how this issue can be fixed.

Thanks for your time.

```
private void Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     //_CurrentItem is an object of the class VM on which the click is executed.
     _CurrentItem = sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as VM
     _CurrentItem.SendStateMessage();
}


private void Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     Console.WriteLine("MouseUp");
}
```

EDIT:

After a bit of time passing by I had another idea to solve the problem, which is also working. I only wait for the MouseDownEvent and if this gets triggered i have a loop where i wait as long as the mouse is pressed, when the mouse is released i could leave the loop and there i inserte the code which i wanted to do in the MouseUPEvent.

Comment: Quacks like a double-click problem, your snippet isn't helpful to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, but it is no double-click problem. you can click in different way, either you click the mouse button and hold it pressed, or you can also click it very fast, and there I have the problem. And as I said i think the server needs to long and so the event is not triggered. but i found no way to solve it.

Comment: To my code snippet: In the method "SendStateMessage()" I send a massage to the server with includes the information if the state is active or not like this line of code:               


ScadaHMIService.SendUserMessage(new MsgUserModuleCommand("IO-Tool", ModuleUid, Enums.UserModuleCommands.Off));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also wait for the MouseDownEvent and if this gets triggered make a loop where you wait as long as the mouse is pressed, when the mouse is released you could leave the loop and inserte there your code which you wanted to do in the MouseUpEvent.

Answer (score 0):

In my case another control consumed the mouseup event. So I catch the mouseup event on level of the top most windows.